# React JS Ant Design Upload - Default Directory

Tags: reactjs, antd

Is there a way to specify the default directory that the Ant Design Upload (https://ant.design/components/upload) component opens to?  For example, if I want it to default open to some directory on a mapped drive like 'E:/dir/name', how would I do that?  None of the options seem to fit that but there's got to be someone who has done this already.

Let me try to give some context, in an attempt to avoid the obvious vanilla web security responses: using react.js + antd with electron.js to build desktop apps out of the web tech stacks we all love.  Using Node fs library to allow users to interact with the filesystem on their local machines.  I would like to know whether it is possible to have it open to any directory I tell it to.  I understand why this is terrible in the context of an app hosted on the good old intertron but this use case is much different as the user base is limited in scope and they actually want this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Actually that's impossible because of security reasons with HTML/Javascript. The ant design Upload component is not more than a simply styled HTML upload input